# Unable to test target end point of postgre. Getting fatal error

Tags: database-migration, aws-dms

I am trying to migrate database using DMS. I have source as MySql and target as postgres.

I have created endpoint and tested for MySql. It does not have any problem. However, when I am trying to configure endpoint for target(postgre) I am getting this error:
Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.31.25.29", user "postgre", database "postgre", no encryption

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `Secure Socket Layer (SSL) mode`

Comment: I am not sure how to get it. I  am bit new. Let me check on how to get answer to your question. Thank you